# hadoop configuration error in runtime with openjdk11

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, openjdk-11, spring-data-hadoop

I am migrating our application to openjdk11 and with this setup my application is throwing below error.
PLease help on this
Note : With Jdk 1.8 the same code and configurations are working fine .
Java version: openjdk 11
Springboot-hadoop : 2.4.0 RELEASE

application properties

```
        spring.hadoop.fsshell.enabled=false
        #hadoop security properties
        hadoop.config.key=hadoop.security.authentication
        hadoop.config.value=Kerberos
        #Hive connection properties
        hive.datasource.keytab=/config/security/sit.001.keytab
        hive.datasource.drivername=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
        hive.datasource.username=ssit.001
        #hive.datasource.password=password
        hive.truststore.file=/config/security/hivetrust.jks
        hive.krb5.conf=/config/security/krb5.conf
        hive.datasource.url=url
        hive.krb5.conf.debug.prop=sun.security.krb5.debug
        hive.krb5.conf.isdebug=true
```

Java changes

```
@Value("${hive.datasource.drivername}")
        private String driverName;
    
        @Value("${hive.datasource.url}")
        private String jdbcUrl;
    
        @Value("${hive.datasource.username}")
        private String userId;
    
        @Value("${hive.datasource.keytab}")
        private String keytab;
    
        @Value("${hive.krb5.conf}")
        private String kerberosConf;
    
        @Value("${hadoop.config.key}")
        public String hadoopConfigKey;
    
        @Value("${hadoop.config.value}")
        public String hadoopConfigValue;
    
        @Bean(name = "hiveDS")
        public DataSource configureHiveDataSource() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            Connection con = null;
    
            // System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", hadoopHome);
            System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", kerberosConf);
            org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
            conf.set(hadoopConfigKey, hadoopConfigValue);
            UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(userId, keytab);
    
            Class.forName(driverName);
    
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
            LOGGER.info("Hive Db Connected");
    
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
            dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
            return dataSource;
        }
        
        @Bean(name = "hiveJdbc")
        public JdbcTemplate getHiveJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("hiveDS") DataSource hiveDS) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(hiveDS);
        }
        
        @Bean(name = "hiveNamedJdbc")
        public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getHiveNamedJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("hiveDS") DataSource hiveNamedDS) {
            return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(hiveNamedDS);
        }
    }
```

2021-04-28T21:18:18.829+0530 [main] ERROR o.s.d.h.c.c.a.AbstractConfiguredAnnotationBuilder - Failed to perform build. Returning null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean name must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
**Error creating bean with name 'hadoopConfiguration' defined in class path resource** [org/springframework/data/hadoop/config/annotation/configuration/SpringHadoopConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is **org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate **[org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration]: Factory method 'configuration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Did you check that your very, very old `hadoop-common-2.2.0` was compatible with Java 9 and above? No, clearly you did not.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter we are currently using the hadoop-common-2.7.1 version . the above property was no where used .

Comment: Does hadoop 2.X version support openjdk 11 ?

from the link i understand it does not support 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions#:~:text=Supported%20JDKs%2FJVMs,be%20supported%20in%20the%20community.&text=Other%20jdks%2Fjvms%20should%20work,expected%2C%20please%20file%20a%20JIRA.

Comment: Hadoop 2.x was released before Java 11, so there's no way it could support it. It requires Java 8

Comment: @OneCricketeer
 thanks for your inputs. As we are moving to openjdk11 , i saw that hadoop-common 3.3.0 would support openjdk11 , however there are so many dependency conflicts between the hadoop-common and hivejdbc latest jar. is there any ways i can make the hive connection work with openjdk11 ?

Comment: I've stopped using Hadoop since 3.x was released, but you shouldn't need to pull hadoop-common dependency if you only need to interact with Hive. If this is a web service, however I'd suggest using Presto or Impala for faster queries, but still won't be as fast as a pre-computed database export using Sqoop into a traditional RDBMS